# Are these shell script characters ( || : ) doing anything useful?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a little shell script that runs anything executable in a designated directory, while passing along two arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd '/foo'
for s in bar/*;
do [ -x $s ] && $s "$1" "$2" || : ;
done
```

Is the `|| :` bit serving any purpose? I wanted the executables to be kicked off asynchronously, so I changed the `;` to a `&`, but is there any reason I shouldn't just do:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd '/foo'
for s in bar/*;
do [ -x $s ] && $s "$1" "$2" &
done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`|| :` (which is often spelled `|| true`) means you don't care whether the command succeeds or not. It forces a successful return status (`$?`).

It is good practice to run shell scripts under the shell's `-e` option so that errors don't go unnoticed. This option can be either activated on the shebang line (`#!/bin/sh -e`) or in the script itself (`set -e`). It causes errors to abort execution of the script.

Since in this case you are not running under `-e`, the `|| :` doesn't make a different because the shell will ignore the result code anyway if the command fails. Furthermore, you are running a command in the background in this case so checking the return code doesn't even make sense.

In general, including `|| true` even if you are not running under `-e` can be good for two reasons:

- To make it compatible with `-e` in case it is ever changed to run under `-e`.
- To serve as documentation to someone reading the shell script that you are conscious of the possibility that this command can fail and that such a failure is explicitely OK.

Comment: Using `-e` is not "good practice". Proper manual error checking is preferred. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Comment: @jordanm that's a fair comment, but notice that even the wiki page you quoted contains a dissenting opinion about the use of `-e` :-) . I'm pretty sure some corporate shell coding policies require the use of `-e`. No doubt there are others which require the opposite!

Comment: Debian maintainer scripts require `-e`, but I consider those special.

Comment: @jordanm I actually consider this a bug in Debian Policy, but, meh. `set -e` is for beginners and people who cobble together maybe 10 lines of batch file. It hinders when doïng proper shell programming. But `set -u` is worse (and positively harmful).